# How to fix the operation is not valid for the state of the transaction?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, entity-framework-6, unity-container

I am trying to implement an asp.net web API and it is my first time trying to implement such a project. I googled a lot.

Many times lost down the road because there is a lot of misguiding articles. Now I accomplished to implement the layered architecture. I have a business entity, business service, data models class library projects and a web API itself. As I said I googled a lot since I have no experience with web API, I decided to use generic repository and unit of work in my solution. My API is working butI get the following error when I load test with 400 users:

> System.Transactions.TransactionException: The operation is not valid for the state of the transaction. ---> System.TimeoutException: Transaction Timeout. The underlying provider failed on Open.

I researched and asked experienced friends, they said I am not disposing of all the DBContexts I am creating. As I am using transient scope, a new DBcontext is created for every action call (controller construction), but unless I call `context.Dispose()` in the action the pools are not released.

Honestly, I am not sure how can I dispose of more.

Controller:

```
namespace Game.Controllers
{
    [System.Web.Http.RoutePrefix("api/v2/game")]
    public class GameController : ApiController
    {
        private readonly IGameServices _gameServices;

        #region Public Constructor  

        public GameController(IGameServices gameServices)
        {
            _gameServices = gameServices;
        }

        #endregion

        [HttpPost, Route("purchase")]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PurchaseGame(RequestDto game)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            //Call Services
            var gameConfirmResponse = await _gameServices.GamePurchase(game);
            switch (gameConfirmResponse.StatusCode)
            {
                case HttpStatusCode.NotFound:
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                case HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError:
                {
                    return InternalServerError();
                }
                case HttpStatusCode.OK:
                {
                    if (gameConfirmResponse.Content == null)
                    {
                        return new System.Web.Http.Results.ResponseMessageResult(
                            Request.CreateErrorResponse((HttpStatusCode) 222, new HttpError("No Results Found")));
                    }

                    var responseStream = await gameConfirmResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                    var resultResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GameConfirmResponse>(responseStream);
                    if (resultResponse.coupons == null)
                    {
                        return new System.Web.Http.Results.ResponseMessageResult(
                            Request.CreateErrorResponse((HttpStatusCode) 222,
                                new HttpError("No Coupons Available for this Game")));
                    }

                    //Transform GameConfirmResponse into DTO for returning result
                    var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
                    {
                        cfg.CreateMap<GameConfirmResponse, GameConfirmResponseDto>();
                        cfg.CreateMap<Coupon, CouponDto>();
                    });
                    var iMapper = config.CreateMapper();
                    var resultDto = iMapper.Map<GameConfirmResponse, GameConfirmResponseDto>(resultResponse);
                    return Ok(resultDto);
                }
                case HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized:
                {
                    return Unauthorized();
                }
                case HttpStatusCode.RequestTimeout:
                {
                    return InternalServerError();
                }
            }

            return Ok(gameConfirmResponse);
        }


        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {

            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

Service:

```
namespace BusinessService
{
    public class GameServices : IGameServices, IDisposable
    {
        private readonly UnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

        public GameServices(UnitOfWork unitOfWork)
        {
            _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        }
        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GamePurchase(RequestDto requestDto)
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = null;

            response = await CallRazerService(requestDto);

            return response;
        }

       private async Task<HttpResponseMessage> CallRazerService(RequestDto requestDto)
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = null;


            using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled))
            {
                //Added to see if I fix the error
                TransactionInterop.GetTransmitterPropagationToken(Transaction.Current);

                //Transform DTO into GameRequest for calling Razer Initiate
                var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
                {
                    cfg.CreateMap<RequestDto, GameRequest>();
                    cfg.CreateMap<GameRequest, GameConfirmRequest>();
                    cfg.CreateMap<GameConfirmResponse, GameConfirmResponseDto>();
                    cfg.CreateMap<Coupon, CouponDto>();
                    cfg.CreateMap<GameRequest, GameRequestDto>();
                });
                var iMapper = config.CreateMapper();
                var gameRequest = iMapper.Map<RequestDto, GameRequest>(requestDto);

                //Unique reference ID
                gameRequest.referenceId = Guid.NewGuid();


                var gameRequestDto = iMapper.Map<GameRequest, GameRequestDto>(gameRequest);

                //Create signature
                gameRequest = Utilities.CreateSignature(gameRequestDto, RequestType.Initiate);

                //Set service
                gameRequest.service = "RAZER";

                //Add initiation request into database
                _unitOfWork.GameRepository.Insert(gameRequest);

                #region Call Razer initiate/confirm

                //Call Razer for initiation
                response = await Utilities.CallRazer(gameRequest, "purchaseinitiation");

                //Read response
                var htmlResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var gameResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GameResponse>(htmlResponse);

                //Adding initiation response into database
                _unitOfWork.GameResponseRepository.Insert(gameResponse);

                if (gameResponse.initiationResultCode == "00")
                {
                    gameRequestDto = iMapper.Map<GameRequest, GameRequestDto>(gameRequest);
                    gameRequestDto.validatedToken = gameResponse.validatedToken;
                    //Create signature
                    var gameConfirmRequest = Utilities.CreateSignature(gameRequestDto, RequestType.Confirm);

                    //Transform DTO into GameRequest for calling Razer Initiate
                    var gameConfirmRequests = iMapper.Map<GameRequest, GameConfirmRequest>(gameConfirmRequest);

                    //Add confirm request into database
                    _unitOfWork.GameConfirmRequestRepository.Insert(gameConfirmRequests);

                    //Call Razer for confirm
                    response = await Utilities.CallRazer(gameConfirmRequest, "purchaseconfirmation");

                    //Read response
                    htmlResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    var gameConfirmResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GameConfirmResponse>(htmlResponse);

                    //Set service
                    gameConfirmResponse.service = "RAZER";
                    //Add confirm response into database
                    _unitOfWork.GameConfirmResponseRepository.Insert(gameConfirmResponse);
                }

                #endregion

                await _unitOfWork.SaveAsync();
                scope.Complete();
            }

            return response;
        }
        public void Dispose()
        {
            _unitOfWork.Dispose();

        }

    }
}
```

Generic Repo (shortened):

```
namespace DataModels
{
    public class GenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
    {
        internal GameContext context;
        internal DbSet<TEntity> dbSet;

        public GenericRepository(GameContext context)
        {
            this.context = context;
            this.dbSet = context.Set<TEntity>();
        }

        #region Public member methods...


        public virtual async Task<List<TEntity>> GetGamesAsync(
            Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> where)
        {
            return await dbSet.Where(where).ToListAsync();
        }

        public virtual async Task<List<T>> GetGameBankProducts<T, TType>(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> where,
            Expression<Func<TEntity, TType>> groupBy, Expression<Func<IGrouping<TType, TEntity>, T>> select)
        {
            return await dbSet.Where(where)
                .GroupBy(groupBy)
                .Select(select)
                .ToListAsync();
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Unit of Work:

```
namespace DataModels
{
    public class UnitOfWork : IDisposable
    {
        private readonly GameContext _context;
        private readonly GenericRepository<GameRequest> gameRequestRepository;
        private readonly GenericRepository<GameResponse> gameResponseRepository;
        private readonly GenericRepository<GameConfirmRequest> gameConfirmRequestRepository;
        private readonly GenericRepository<GameConfirmResponse> gameConfirmResponseRepository;
        private readonly GenericRepository<GameBank> gameBankRepository;
        private readonly GenericRepository<GameBankPin> gameBankPinRepository;
        private readonly GenericRepository<ConfirmCancel> confirmCancelRepository;
        private readonly GenericRepository<Recon> reconRepository;
        private readonly GenericRepository<Company> userRepository;

        public UnitOfWork(GameContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public GenericRepository<GameRequest> GameRepository
        {
            get
            {
                return this.gameRequestRepository ?? new GenericRepository<GameRequest>(_context);
            }
        }

        public GenericRepository<GameResponse> GameResponseRepository
        {
            get
            {
                return this.gameResponseRepository ?? new GenericRepository<GameResponse>(_context);
            }
        }

        public GenericRepository<GameConfirmRequest> GameConfirmRequestRepository
        {
            get
            {
                return this.gameConfirmRequestRepository ?? new GenericRepository<GameConfirmRequest>(_context);
            }
        }

        public GenericRepository<GameConfirmResponse> GameConfirmResponseRepository
        {
            get
            {
                return this.gameConfirmResponseRepository ?? new GenericRepository<GameConfirmResponse>(_context);
            }
        }

        public GenericRepository<GameBank> GameBankRepository
        {
            get
            {
                return this.gameBankRepository ?? new GenericRepository<GameBank>(_context);
            }
        }

        public GenericRepository<GameBankPin> GameBankPinRepository
        {
            get
            {
                return this.gameBankPinRepository ?? new GenericRepository<GameBankPin>(_context);
            }
        }

        public GenericRepository<ConfirmCancel> ConfirmCancelRepository
        {
            get
            {
                return this.confirmCancelRepository ?? new GenericRepository<ConfirmCancel>(_context);
            }
        }

        public GenericRepository<Recon> ReconRepository
        {
            get
            {
                return this.reconRepository ?? new GenericRepository<Recon>(_context);
            }
        }

        public GenericRepository<Company> UserRepository
        {
            get
            {
                return this.userRepository ?? new GenericRepository<Company>(_context);
            }
        }


        public void Save()
        {
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }

        public async Task SaveAsync()
        {
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }

        private bool disposed = false;

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (!this.disposed)
            {
                if (disposing)
                {
                    _context.Dispose();
                }
            }
            this.disposed = true;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Unity config:

```
namespace Game
{

    public static class UnityConfig
    {
        #region Unity Container
        private static Lazy<IUnityContainer> container =
          new Lazy<IUnityContainer>(() =>
          {
              var container = new UnityContainer();
              RegisterTypes(container);
              return container;
          });


        public static IUnityContainer Container => container.Value;
        #endregion


        public static void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container)
        {
            // Default empty Time manager!
            container.RegisterType<IGameServices, GameServices>().RegisterType<UnitOfWork>(new TransientLifetimeManager());
            container.RegisterType<IUserValidate, UserValidate>(new TransientLifetimeManager());


        }
    }
}
```

People keep telling me the best practice is to use "using" but how can I use using in the controller for the Dbcontext? I couldn't find a way.

**Update1:**
I have been told that instead of transaction scope, I should use dbcontext transaciton (`using(var dbContextTransaction = context.Database.BeginTransaction())`). I couldn't find a way to use dbcontext transaction in my Service class. I am injecting unit of work in Service class.

**Update2:**
Should I implement inside of unit of work and remove transactionscope inside of the Service?
UOW Save:

```
public void Save(){
try{
using (var transaction = _context.Database.BeginTransaction()){
try
{
_context.SaveChanges();
transaction.Commit();
}
catch
{
transaction.Rollback();
throw;
}
}
}catch (Exception e)
{//TODO:Logging}}
```

Comment: The basic idea is to register the dbContext (UoW) as belonging to the HttpRequest scope. The services can then be transient. The container should call DIspose() and you shouldn't need to help.

Comment: Also, SaveChanges() already uses a Transaction.

Comment: @HenkHolterman, so what I understand is that the Unity configuration is wrong? I don't get what you mean by SaveChanges(). Dou you mean it is not needed to add begin transaction inside the Save in UOW?

Comment: I think so but I don't know Unity that well. Any reason not to switch to asp.net core? There it is all built-in.

Comment: I do not understand why you're using some kind of UnitOfWork but still create a transaction inside your service. My understanding of a UnitOfWork is that it handles all that stuff. So I would expect a BeginTransaction/Commit/Rollback method in your UoW. By the way your transaction does too much stuff! The transaction should be as small and short as possible. So remove everything that does not relate to DB calls from your transaction. Maybe your issue will gone then.

Comment: I wish I could but it is sort of a little bit late for this project. If I can solve my problem, I will definitely change it to core. Hope someone experience with Unity can help.

Comment: @user743414 so you say I have to add BeginTransaction/Commit/Rollback in UOW like my Update2.

Comment: @Fake I would go that way. Yes. Because your UoW is your API to access DB stuff. That's why it should also handle related tasks.

Comment: @user743414 Then I don't need the transactionscope in my service right?

Comment: Exactly. But you still have to take care not to create long running transactions. Just as an advice checkout this generic repo approach: https://garywoodfine.com/generic-repository-pattern-net-core/ Repo:https://github.com/threenine/Threenine.Data It has some advantages compared to your choice. It's more a general design thing, and it does force you to do some things right from the beginning.

Comment: @user743414 thank you, I will try and let you know.

Comment: I made a load test with 1000 users and 10 seconds ramp-up time, there were no errors :) I just removed the transaction scope from the code.